# How to use web3j to observe transaction of ERC20 token

Tags: web3j

Leverage Web3j TransactionObservable together with filter, i can monitor ETH/ETC transactions as following code snippet illustrates.

```
web3j.transactionObservable().filter(tx -> isWantedTransaction(tx)).subscribe(processTransaction,errorHandler,OnCompleteHandler);
```

How to implement same function with web3j for customerized ERC20 tokens?

Comment: Hi, I'm solving the same issue. Have u found a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Web3j ethLogObservable** to subscribe to particular events on a smart contract.

**1. Definition of the ERC20 `Transfer` Event**

```
// event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
final Event TRANSFER_EVENT = new Event("Transfer", 
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(
          new TypeReference<Address>(true) {},
          new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, 
          new TypeReference<Uint256>(false) {}));
```

**2. Build the filter**

A web3j Log filter is composed of:

- `startBlock`: Filter events by block number lower bound (special keywords: `earliest` and `latest`)
- `endBlock`: Filter events by block number higher bound (special keywords: `earliest` and `latest`)
- `contractAddress`: Filter events by contract address

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, contractAddress);
```

At this point, you will get all the events for the contract deployed at `contractAddress` between `startBlock` and `endBlock`. If you want to monitor only `Transfer`, you can add a topic (sort of filter)

```
filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(TRANSFER_EVENT));
```

**3. Subscribe to the observable and filter by transaction if needed**

The latest part consists to subscribe to the ethLog observable with the filter configured above. It is also possible to add a filter on transactionHash (like you example)

```
web3j.ethLogObservable(filter)
        .filter(event -> isWantedTransaction(event.getTransactionHash()))
        .subscribe(event -> ...);
```

[More details](https://docs.web3j.io/filters.html)

Comment: Is it possible to in addition to the above filters, filter it based on a specific wallet and only incoming transactions?